# MinHeap: which approach is best when adding nodes to an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, data-structures, min-heap

I'm working on building a minheap in Ruby and was wondering what the implications would be of using the push method vs an assignment operator. (This is just a theoretical question to understand Ruby better!)

```
@items = Array.new()

def insert(node)
  if @items.empty?
    @items.push(node)
  end 
end 

def insert(node)
  if @items.empty?
    root = node 
  end 
end
```

Comment: There is a simple difference between the two snippets: the second doesn't do anything. It is unclear what further information you seek.

Comment: Ah, ok. I thought the second version would create a root node, like in a binary search tree.